# Authentic scriptural source of deciding Ēkādaśī

Tags: vaishnavism, vrata, ekadashi, smarta

There are two types of Ēkādaśī.

**Smārta Ēkādaśī**: If Ēkādaśī has started by sunrise or *Sūryōdaya*, then it's Ēkādaśī fasting on that day. This is followed by the followers of Ādi Śaṅkarācārya.

**Vaiṣṇava or Bhāgavata Ēkādaśī**: If Ēkādaśī has started 96 minutes before sunrise or *Aruṇōdaya*, then it's Ēkādaśī fasting on that day. This is followed by Vaiṣṇava like followers of Madhvācārya and Caitanya Mahāprabhu.

---

I have two questions regarding this.

1. Are there any sources from Āgamas or Purāṇas or Smr̥tis which decide when the Ēkādaśī should be fixed?
2. I was hearing a Pravacana by Madhva Scholar who said following:
   Ēkādaśī on Sunrise amounts to sin and in Mahābhārata, Gāndhāri did Ēkādaśī which had Daśamī Sparśa, probably the first kind of Ēkādaśī, and that is why she had bad children. Is this mentioned in Mahābhārata? Does it validate the second kind of Ēkādaśī calculation?

Comment: You already provide reference in mahabharata

Comment: It's simple when you do sandhyavanda one should sankalpa on thiti sandhya vandana should be started 48 mins before sunrise so thitih will dasami after  sunrise or during sunrise the the tithi can changed what matter tithi during sankalpa is important  so you sankalpa for dashmi cannot fast on that day just because ekadashi falls during or after sunrise

Comment: All the sources you are questioning are smriti, not sruti. There will be conflict between the smritis depending upon your sectarian preference.

Comment: @PrasannaR yes but that us jot reference. Please give chapter and verse number along with translation and original Sanskrit shlokas

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda hello, but I could not find any reference to calculation any where. Let it be contradictory to one another, atleast give some reference where the calculation is mentioned in any smriti or purana.

Comment: Do you know about Hindu fasts like Shiva Ratri, Ekadashi etc.? They are not mentioned in Vedas but so what? Vedas, Smritis, Puranas are all Hindu scriptures and respected by all Hindus @SwamiVishwananda

Comment: @PrasannaR give the chapter, verse number in which it is mentioned?? Also give any reference regarding calculations.

Comment: Vaishnavas have always attempted to create parallel systems of smriti. For example Sanatana Goswami in Haribhaktivilasa advocates usage of Vishnu's prasada in sradhha ceremony which is refuted by Kamalakara Bhatta in Nirnayasindhu. Gopalabhatta Goswami in Satkriyasaradipika even goes as far as to declare worship of deceased ancestors in sraddha ceremony to be sin for Vaishnavas & advocates worship of the Guru instead of pitris.

Comment: @AnubrataBit just ignore the controversies. Do we have any old scripture among ancient authentic Agamas, Smritis or Puranas which speak of the calculations?

Comment: The version of scriptures available in printed forms have their own limitations. I would suggest you to consult the nibandhas.

Comment: @AnubrataBit what are nibandhas?

Comment: Due to word limit of comments, I'm unable to give a complete explanation. Read https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/51688/22857 this for your query.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, both the methods of performing the Ēkādaśī *vrata* (viz. the Smārta way, and the Vaiṣṇava or Bhāgavata way), may be deemed correct for the respective followers of their sect.

It is a well-known fact that there can be local, regional, and sectarian variations in certain rituals and beliefs within Hinduism, and there's never a "one-correct way" or "one correct doctrine" for several aspects within Hinduism. That's why we have different sects (Vaiṣṇavism,  Śaivism, Śaāktism, etc.). We even have two schemes of the lunar months (Pūrṇimānta & Amānta) to name the Hindu calendar months. All this follows the overarching letter and spirit of the famous verse in the Ṛgveda  - *Ékaṃ sád víprā bahudhā́ vadanti*  - [[Ṛgveda 1.164.46](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/30012/how-have-traditional-vedic-commentators-intepreted-rig-veda-1-164-46)].

In any case, the Nārada Mahā-Purāṇa dwells deep into this, from the Vaiṣṇava perspective justifying the Vaiṣṇava way of Ēkādaśī fast, all the while still maintaining that the Smārta have a "different-method", albeit not correct from the Vaiṣṇava perspective.

> #### [Chapter 37](https://archive.org/details/dli.bengal.10689.12976/page/n410/mode/1up?view=theater),
>
> Uttarabhāga, Nārada Mahā-Purāṇa
>
> > 8. O chaste lady, **the *Smārtas* (those who follow *Smṛtis*) eschew the *Ekadaśī* that is overlapped (by *Daśami*) at sunrise. Those who are devoid of any desire (from this *Vrata*) leave off (the *Ekādasi*)
> >    that is overlapped by *Daśami* even at midnight.**
>
> > 9. It is well-known in all the worlds that the *Daśami Tithi* belongs to Yama. O, sinless lady, you must station yourself in its vicinity on
> >    the border.
>
> > 10. O splendid lady, thanks to this, even the task of the *Devas* can be realized. Staying along the border of Daśami, you will traverse
> >     along with the Sun and the Moon too.
>
> > 11. In order to dispel your sins, you move about the various sacred places on the Earth. You can have the benefit of the rite of *Ekādaśī*
> >     within the period of time between *Aruņodaya* (dawn) and sunrise.
>
> > 12. If anyone observes the holy rite of *Ekādaśī* on the day when it has been occupied by you, he will be the person assisting you, o
> >     beloved one of the *Devas*. The period of two *Muhūrtas* of the dawn
> >     should be known (as your period of occupancy).
>
> > - 13-14. The number of *Muhūrtas* of the day and of the night are remembered to be fifteen for each. They vary when the extent of time
> >   of the day and the night varies becoming short and long (by turns).
> >   This extent of time should be understood by the process of
> >   *Trairāśika* (Rule of Three).
>
> > 15. You come (and occupy your place) after the thirteenth *Muhūrta* of the night. O lady of pure smiles, deriving the merit of those who
> >     observe fast on that day, be happy.
>
> > - 16-17 O Mohini, the time marked by the early dawn has been assigned as the abode to you for the purpose of re-establishing Yama, to
> >   destroy the path to Vaikuntha, to increase the number of heretics and
> >   to accumulate sins.
>
> > 18. O splendid lady, enjoy the benefit of the merit of those persons who assiduously observe the holy rite of *Ekādaśī* on the day of your
> >     occupancy and overlapping.
>
> .....
>
> > 22. For the delusion of the people, she stationed herself in the transition period of time of *Daśami* (that is called *Sūryavihīnā*
> >     (devoid of the Sun or *Aruṇodaya-Vedha*). She enjoys the whole day in
> >     the form of Krcchrānta for the downfall of men into hell.
>
> .....
>
> > - 25. **If *Daśami* touches Ekādasi at the time of Sunrise what is called *Sūryodaya Vedha* it is always condemned. The sunrise that is
> >       not touched will be conducive to the fascination of men.**
>
> > - 26-27. That *Daśami* day must be eschewed even if it extends to a fourth of the period and is also invisible if the enjoyment of the
> >   favorable *Yoga* is desired. O large-eyed lady, your name Mohini, as
> >   people call you, is significant indeed. After deluding the people you
> >   get them recorded on the canvas (i.e. the record of their acts kept by
> >   Citragupta.)”
>
> English Translation by Motilal Banarsidass Publishers

---

---

## To summarize:

- Answer to Question 1:

<sup>*(As noted by the Translator in the footnotes:)*-</sup>

An Ēkādaśī, when affected by *Aruṇodaya-Vedha*, should not be observed i.e. if the 10th *Tithi*, *Daśami*, extends on a civil day beyond 56 *ghaṭikās* from sunrise and *Ēkādaśī* follows and continues for the whole of the next day, there is *Aruṇodaya-Vedha* and such affected or penetrated (*viddhā*) *Ēkādaśī* is not to be observed. This period of two *muhūrtas* before sunrise (i.e. *Aruṇodaya Vedha*) is assigned to Mohini for occupation and the merit of people observing *Aruṇodaya Viddhā Ēkādaśī* goes to Mohini.

**The Smärtas (non-Vaişnavas) however, are not governed by the doctrine of *Aruṇodaya-Vedha*.**

---

- Answer to Question 2:

As regards "the Gandhāri incident" - the Garuda Purana [Ch. 75](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-garuda-purana-dutt/d/doc122605.html) - Brihaspati Samhita, does say that - "*She fasted on the day of the tenth phase of the moon, and lost her hundred sons in consequence"*, but, it *does **not** say* (as asked by the OP) that Gāndhāri did Ēkādaśī which had Daśamī Sparśa, and that is why she had bad children, and I don't know if this is mentioned in any recension Mahabharata too, if at all.

**So, *Yes*, from the Vaiṣṇava or Bhāgavata perspective, as mentioned in the Garuḍamahāpurāṇa, "the Gandhāri incident" does validate the second kind of Ēkādaśī calculation!**